# example of a function $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose set of points of discontinuity is $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need an example of a function $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose set of points 
of discontinuity is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What are you thoughts on this?

Answer (score 13):

Enumerate the rationals, $q_n$. Now consider:

$$\Large f(x)=\sum_{q_n<x}\frac1{2^n}$$

I am leaving you with the details of proving this function satisfies the conditions you ask for.

Comment: I'm confused about the downvote.

Comment: Additionally, it's bounded, monotone and every discontinuity is a jump discontinuity.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative, known as [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), sometimes the (modified) Dirichlet function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$}\\
1/q&\text{if $x=p/q$ with $p$, $q$ integers with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q>0$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think you're confusing your terms. The [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) usually refers to the indicator function of the rationals (over the reals). What you have there is [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Comment: @kahen: I *did* say *sometimes* … Wolfram MathWorld [agrees](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) that it is sometimes called that. It is the name I learned for it; the wikipedia page you refer to says it is sometimes known as the *modified* Dirichlet function, so there is ample room for confusion. But I'll update my answer anyhow to bring it in line with what seems to be accepted terminology.

Answer (score 5):

As in Asaf's answer, enumerate the rationals to get $q_n$. Define $f(q_n)=1/n$ and $f(x)=0$ for irrationals.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this answer. Why?

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to be in sync with the downvote on my answer? :-)